# DevExpress Winforms Grid how to set focus to a row

Tags: winforms, xtragrid, devexpress-windows-ui

To take advantage of DevExpress Winforms XtraGrid incremental search, the user must first click on a row before typing.

How to set focus on the first row programmatically, to avoid that step?

In the control's DataSourceChanged event, I've tried setting focus to the control itself

```
       gridControl1.Focus();
```

or to its default view

```
      gridControl1.DefaultView.Focus();
```

but neither had the desired effect.

Also have tried setting the FocusedRowHandle:

```
        gridControl1.DataSource = T;
        this.gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
private void gridControl1_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.ActiveControl = this.gridControl1;
  this.gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = 0;
}
```

Comment: Setting the ActiveControl was the answer. Thanks